# I need some help with Sakai 2.7.1 and Tomcat 5.5.33, in regards to SQL issues

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, amazon-web-services, sakai

Today I managed to recreate the farms with Scalr.net and apparently after a few times restarting tomcat and fixing issues, I get this error once again.  The thing is I was using MySQL with a clean install on the entire server, that includes Java 6.1_24, Tomcat 5.5.33, Sakai 2.7.1.  The issue I keep running into is user denied when the fact that I have this user in the MySQL Instance, as well giving it complete remote access with sakai@% and even this is not working when it was working about an hour ago since this post was made.

```
... Continued from above log, everything before logs just fine
2011-03-31 18:31:14,120  WARN main org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy - Could not retrieve default auto-commit and transaction isolation settings
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Error preloading the connection pool
... continued over 400+ lines...
```

Here is another error in regards to the access denied error...

```
2011-03-31 18:31:16,854  WARN main org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sakai'@'ec2-50-17-184-70.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
.... continued....
```

I now get this error whenever I startup, this is with a fresh install of tomcat/sakai

```
SEVERE: Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: ec2-72-44-56-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com: ec2-72-44-56-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com
java.net.UnknownHostException: ec2-72-44-56-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com: ec2-72-44-56-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

(This most recent error (Localhost) was simply fixed by restarting the amazon aws instance.  Thankfully)  Although I keep getting the same errors even with a fresh install... Almost as if the information is being refreshed from a cache... Or something

Comment: I have added 
sakai  %  global  ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes 
sakai  %.compute-1.amazonaws.com  global  ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes

and still no favor of working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I may have figured out how to fix this problem.  It has nothing to do with mysql, or the apache server itself.  It has to do with the failure of Scalr.net not Initializing the IP or something of that sort.  After doing some research I found some issues with the HostInit issues such as....

```
Cannot deliver message 'HostInit' (message_id: af9dcfdb-a09e-4971-bdb7-7871b3f7e21c) via REST to server '50.17.135.98' (server_id: e49cfec9-5bcb-44d1-bbc5-fde32450fc89). Error: 0 Timeout was reached; connect() timed out! (http://50.17.135.98:8013/control)
Cannot deliver message 'BlockDeviceAttached' (message_id: a153d83f-3d96-4d53-920a-ccb80701675a) via REST to server '50.17.135.98' (server_id: e49cfec9-5bcb-44d1-bbc5-fde32450fc89). Error: 0 Timeout was reached; connect() timed out! (http://50.17.135.98:8013/control)
Cannot deliver message 'HostUp' (message_id: 1adde27c-9982-4551-b266-c3c432d1dd44) via REST to server '50.17.135.98' (server_id: e49cfec9-5bcb-44d1-bbc5-fde32450fc89). Error: 0 Timeout was reached; connect() timed out! (http://50.17.135.98:8013/control)
Cannot deliver message 'HostInit' (message_id: f1aa4b14-ef57-4361-ae56-87702d674b11) via REST to server '50.17.135.98' (server_id: e49cfec9-5bcb-44d1-bbc5-fde32450fc89). Error: 0 Timeout was reached; connect() timed out! (http://50.17.135.98:8013/control)
```

So what I did was I made a snapshot image of the apache server/mysql etc. and terminated them allowing the recreation of the instance and this managed to solve the problem in one manner.

Answer (score 0):

As with the last question [you posted on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493886/i-am-getting-some-issues-with-tomcat-5-5-33-and-sakai-2-7-1-that-i-am-getting-con), the error message seems very clear: the user `'sakai'@...` does not have access to login to the database you have set it up to. I recommend taking a look at [the Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html) to understand how to administer the user accounts to find out if you've missed a setting somewhere to allow this account to have access.

Comment: I do have have access heh thats the fact. the user is 'sakai'@'%' therefore it should have access. The fact is that when I clear tomcat/sakai as a fresh install it is able to connect, several times until eventually it starts to complain... IDK if it is because of to many connection attempts or what... Thats why I am asking... I do get another error or well Warning which is the first one... IE Error preloading the connection pool... What exactly does this mean? And how can I fix that? Because I am sure that is the problem affecting the access denied.